# Mongodb $match using index on joined($lookup) documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, lookup

***General Issue***

Lets say we have users in our system, and each user have **EXACTLY** one team.
Now, there is an ability in the system which allows searching teams by user firstname, lastname and team name.
Such search should be well-indexed because it must not consume every single ram the server has.

***Visual Objects***

```
class User
{
    public ObjectId Id;
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
}

class Team
{
    public ObjectId Id;
    public ObjectId UserId;
    public string Name;
}
```

***SQL Equivalent***

```
SELECT
  Id,
  UserId
FROM
  Teams
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Users ON Users.Id = Teams.UserId
WHERE
  Users.FirstName LIKE "%someting%"
  OR Users.LastName LIKE "%someting%"
  OR Teams.Name LIKE "%someting%"
```

***What I have now***

```
db.getCollection('Teams').aggregate([
{$lookup:
     {
       from: "Users",
       localField: "UserId",
       foreignField: "Id",
       as: "user"
     }},
{$match : {$or : [{Name : /somename/}, {"user.0.FirstName": /somename/}, {"user.0.LastName" : /somename/}]}}
```

***Problem***

It works, but...
I cannot figure how I need to index stuff or change things in order for the query to use indexes.

It doesn't seem like indexing Team's or User's relevant fields helps.